postMessage to iFrame not working through GTM
I'm facing a strange situation. I wrote a code which should send a variable to an iFrame embedded on my page through postMessage().
The parent-page is: "https://www.bestcars.com (example)
The iFrame-page is: "https://info.bestcars.com (example)
I triggered the following code in GTM when the parent-page is loaded:
(function(window) {
     var checkIframe = setInterval(function() {
         var iframe = document.querySelector('.p-form-content'); 
         var urlobject = "Hello";
         iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(urlobject, 'https://info.bestcars.com');
         clearInterval(checkIframe);
      }, 100); 
})(window);

But, that doesn't work. The console shows the error-message:

VM1359:1  Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://info.bestcars.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://www.bestcars.com').

The strange thing: it works when I'm executing the same code on the same page through the console in Chrome.
Can you help?
Thanks,

Is your iframe initially loading its content from https://info.bestcars.com already? Or is it perhaps a page from https://www.bestcars.com, that then redirects to the other one at some later point?

Hi @C3roe. Wow, that seems to be the reason! If I increase the interval to 2000 ms, it works. That seems to be quite a long forwarding time. Many thanks for your help!

Maybe you need to wait for the document in the iframe to be loaded? Here is an example where the document of the iframe looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('message', e => {
        document.body.innerHTML += `<div>${e.data}</div>`;
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>test</p>
  </body>
</html>

And use the load event on the iframe:


document.querySelector('iframe').addEventListener('load', e => {
  setInterval(function(){
    e.target.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');
  }, 1000);
});
<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sPgogIDxoZWFkPgogICAgPHNjcmlwdD4KICAgICAgd2luZG93LmFkZEV2ZW50TGlzdGVuZXIoJ21lc3NhZ2UnLCBlID0+IHsKICAgICAgICBkb2N1bWVudC5ib2R5LmlubmVySFRNTCArPSBgPGRpdj4ke2UuZGF0YX08L2Rpdj5gOwogICAgICB9KTsKICAgIDwvc2NyaXB0PgogIDwvaGVhZD4KICA8Ym9keT4KICAgIDxwPnRlc3Q8L3A+CiAgPC9ib2R5Pgo8L2h0bWw+"></iframe>



